# How to create a conditional which checks if one or another condition is true in plain TeX?

Tags: conditionals, plain-tex

I need to make a conditional like this:

```
IF #1 > \variable OR #1 = 0
THEN
   PRINT "True"
ELSE
   PRINT "False"
```

If `#1` is greater than `\variable` or is equal to `0`, then it it true. The value only contains integers of 0 or greater. There are never any decimals.

I have this conditional in plain TeX, which checks if `#1` is greater than `\variable`, but I do not know how to add the `#1 = 0` part.

```
\ifnum0#1>\variable
    True
\else
    False
\fi
```

How can I create a conditional that checks if at least one of these conditionals is true?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\if\ifnum#1>\variable T\else\ifnum#1=0 T\else F\fi\fi T%
  TRUE
\else
  FALSE
\fi
```

`\if` expands tokens until two non-expandable tokens remain. If one of the conditions is true, then the expansion is `T`, otherwise `F`. This is compared with the last `T`
in the line.

- Advantage: `TRUE` is not duplicated as in

  ```
  \ifnum#1>\variable
    TRUE
  \else
    \ifnum#1=0 %
      TRUE
    \else
      FALSE
    \fi
  \fi
  ```
- Advantage: All number parsings are stopped by well defined tokens. Example: The token `T` stops the scanning of the number `\variable`. If the `TRUE` part starts with a number
  `123abc` and `\variable` is defined as `5`

  ```
  \def\variable{5}
  \ifnum#1>\variable
    123abc
  \fi
  ```

  Then `#1` must be greater than `5123`!

  Depending on the definition of `\variable` the evaluation of `\variable` as number
  might skip a first space of the `TRUE` part.
- Advantage: The conditionals are well matched, thus this construct can also be used
  inside other conditionals. If TeX skips a conditional branch it only checks the
  command tokens for real `\if...` primitives, `\else`, `\fi`, and `\or` (for `\ifcase`).

  For example with a macro `\ifOR` the following is not well matched:

  ```
  \ifOR{\ifnum#1>\variable}{\ifnum#1=0}
    TRUE
  \else
    FALSE
  \fi
  ```

  `\ifOR` does not count as macro, but there are two `\ifnum`, but only one `\fi`.
- Disadvantage: The `\if` condition is not easy to read.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way, where the first macros are essentially from `lambda.sty` by Alan Jeffrey:

```
\def\True#1#2{#1}
\def\False#1#2{#2}
\def\Or#1#2{#1\True{#2}}
\def\gobblefalse\else\gobbletrue\fi#1#2{\fi#1}
\def\gobbletrue\fi#1#2{\fi#2}
\def\TeXif#1{#1\gobblefalse\else\gobbletrue\fi}

\def\Morethan#1#2{\TeXif{\ifnum#1>#2 }}
\def\Equals#1#2{\TeXif{\ifnum#1=#2 }}

\def\Test#1{%
  \Or
    {\Morethan{#1}\variable}
    {\Equals{#1}0}
  {True}
  {False}}

\newcount\variable
\variable=5

\Test{2} \Test{5} \Test{10} \Test{0}

\variable=2
\Test{2} \Test{5} \Test{0} \Test{1}
\bye
```

I have a feeling there is a possibility for a higher level abstraction in the spirit of Schemesque `cond` here somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
\def\variable{5}
\def\test#1{%
  \ifnum0#1>\variable
    True
  \else
    \ifnum0#1=0
      True
    \else
      False
    \fi
  \fi
}
\test{6} \par
\test{5} \par
\test{4} \par
\test{3} \par
\test{2} \par
\test{1} \par
\test{0}
```

which outputs

```
True
False
False
False
False
False
True
```

Note that this would only work for positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

My solution(s) has the some idea as [Werner's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75487/16595) but extend this a little:

```
\def\variable{5}

% Solution 1
\def\ifOr#1#2{%
 \csname%
  \ifnum#1%
    iftrue%
  \else%
    \ifnum#2%
      iftrue%
    \else%
      iffalse%
    \fi%
  \fi%
 \endcsname%
}
\def\test#1{%
  \ifOr{0#1>\variable}{#1=0}%
    True%
  \else%
    False%
  \fi%
}

% Solution 2
\def\ifOR#1#2{%
 \csname%
  #1%
    iftrue%
  \else%
    #2%
      iftrue%
    \else%
      iffalse%
    \fi%
  \fi%
 \endcsname%
}
\def\Test#1{%
  \ifOR{\ifnum0#1>\variable}{\ifnum#1=0}%
    True%
  \else%
    False%
  \fi%
}

\test{8} \Test{8} \par
\test{4} \Test{4} \par
\test{3} \Test{3} \par
\test{2} \Test{2} \par
\test{1} \Test{1} \par
\test{0} \Test{0}
```